# PHP обработка формы: сохранение множества элементов

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Вопрос в следующем: есть БД MySQL и страница PHP, из базы данных выводится `n` количество форм для ввода данных в БД и соответственно у каждой формы есть своя кнопка `submit` (например список товаров, в котором `id`, название, цена и кнопка сохранить).

Хочу сделать одну кнопку `submit`, а не `n` кнопок и кликать каждый раз сохранить для каждого элемента. Код думаю бессмыслено выкладывать - не прошу сделать за меня, направьте в правильное русломои мысли на этот счет, что нужно передавать массив PHP скрипту который будет массив разбирать и построчно записывать в бд (в правильном направлении я думаю, или есть более элегантное решение?) можно привести простейший пример на `jquery + ajax + php` или `php`, изменить под свои нужды думаю не составит труда. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный набор данных, полученных из базы:

```
$forms = [
    [
        'id'    => 1,
        'name'  => 'Name 1',
        'price' => 100
    ],
    [
        'id'    => 2,
        'name'  => 'Name 2',
        'price' => 200
    ],
    [
        'id'    => 3,
        'name'  => 'Name 3',
        'price' => 300
    ]
];
```

Вам следует вывести все поля в одной форме. Имя каждого поля должно содержать id своей записи.

```
<form id="form">
    <?php foreach($forms as $form): ?>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="forms[<?php echo $form['id']; ?>][id]"    value="<?php echo $form['id']; ?>">
            <input type="text"   name="forms[<?php echo $form['id']; ?>][name]"  value="<?php echo $form['name']; ?>">
            <input type="text"   name="forms[<?php echo $form['id']; ?>][price]" value="<?php echo $form['price']; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Таким образом, при сабмите сформируется массив, аналогичный исходному.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.post('post.php', $(this).serializeArray(), function(response) {
                console.log('success');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

И, наконец, скрипт, который обновляет данные в базе.

```
$forms = $_REQUEST['forms'];

foreach ($forms as $form) {
    // UPDATE table SET name = $form[name], ... WHERE id = $form[id]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все понятно, и по существу. Сегодня попробую реализовать=)) +1

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно прямо несколько (товаров) выводить - думаю самый оптимальный способ - единая форма с одной кнопкой, массив в php, а он там пусть разбирается что и куда сохранять.
Если не нужно несколько сразу - выдавать цепочкой (один товар за другим) и по очереди сохранять.
Ну или комбинация того и другого - выдавать пачку, после изменения - автоматом сохранять через ajax, убирать со страницы (и подставлять новый).

Comment: В принципе понятно, тоже думал кокраз в направлении единой формы и передачи массива, вопрос в том как этот массив  передавать или правельнее сказать сделать? Всмысле есть n колличество инпутов в одной большой форме, приэтом сгенерированных пхп, так вот эти интупты будут иметь одно и тоже название или я чего-то не понимаю в цикле им можно задать разные название цыфрами например. Вопрос то в том как эту форму обработать? Писать фому в переменную и передавать скрипту или передавать скрипту как-то иначе?
<form>
<input1><input2><input3>
<input1><input2><input3>
<submit>
</form>